# Python - PyTorch: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am working with PyTorch on a Text Classification problem with BERT. This is the PyTorch Dataset format I am using but when I try to access the inputs from the Dataset I get an error.

### PyTorch Dataset

The Dataset Returns a Dictionary containing : `ids`, `mask`, `token_type_ids`, `targets`

```
class JigsawDataset:
    def __init__(self, df, train_transforms = None):
        self.comment_text = df["comment_text"].values
        self.target = df["toxic"].values
        self.tokenizer = config.BERT_TOKENIZER
        self.max_len = config.MAX_LEN
        self.langs = df["lang"].values
        self.train_transforms = train_transforms

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.comment_text)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        comment_text = str(self.comment_text[item])
        comment_text = " ".join(comment_text.split())
        lang = self.langs[item]
        
        if self.train_transforms:
            comment_text, _ = self.train_transforms(data=(comment_text, lang))['data']

        inputs = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            comment_text,
            None,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=self.max_len,
            pad_to_max_length=True,
            truncation=True,
        )

        ids = inputs["input_ids"]
        mask = inputs["attention_mask"]
        token_type_ids = inputs["token_type_ids"]

        data_loader_dict = {}
        data_loader_dict["ids"] = torch.tensor(ids, dtype=torch.long)
        data_loader_dict["mask"] = torch.tensor(mask, dtype=torch.long)
        data_loader_dict["token_type_ids"] = torch.tensor(token_type_ids, dtype=torch.long)
        data_loader_dict["targets"] = torch.tensor(self.target[item], dtype=torch.float)
        
        
        return data_loader_dict
```

### Relevant Code which Gives Error

In this case I am trying to load only 1 Sample and make it to the format of the PyTorch Dataset

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
df = df.head(1) # Trying with only 1 Sample
dataset = JigsawDataset(df)

ids = dataset["ids"]    # Error occurs at this line
mask = dataset["mask"]
token_type_ids = ["token_type_ids"]
```

### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-4608dd623cac> in <module>
      3 dataset = JigsawDataset(df)
      4 
----> 5 ids = dataset["ids"]    # Error occurs at this line
      6 mask = dataset["mask"]
      7 token_type_ids = ["token_type_ids"]

<ipython-input-40-121d8aa71516> in __getitem__(self, item)
     13 
     14     def __getitem__(self, item):
---> 15         comment_text = str(self.comment_text[item])
     16         comment_text = " ".join(comment_text.split())
     17         lang = self.langs[item]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we could help you more.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) the method 'values' of panda's DataFrame object returns a numpy array.
in your code, you set the attribute 'self.comment_text' to the numpy array returnd by  'df["comment_text"].values' (line 3 in code box 1).
Numpy arrays do not accept strings as indices.
It's hard to give you an answer i'm sure will work without testing it, but i would start from setting the attribute 'self.comment_text' to the dataframe or a copy of it instead of only the values it holds.

I would change this:

```
class JigsawDataset:
    def __init__(self, df, train_transforms = None):
        self.comment_text = df["comment_text"].values
        self.target = df["toxic"].values
        self.tokenizer = config.BERT_TOKENIZER
.
.
.
```

to this:

```
class JigsawDataset:
    def __init__(self, df, train_transforms = None):
        self.comment_text = df["comment_text"]
        self.target = df["toxic"].values
        self.tokenizer = config.BERT_TOKENIZER
.
.
.
```

Comment: I am not very sure about what change I should make based on your suggestion. Can you please elaborate a bit or demonstrate a small example?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.

**Incorrect Code**

```
ids = dataset["ids"]    
mask = dataset["mask"]
token_type_ids = ["token_type_ids"]
```

**Correct Code**

```
ids = dataset[0]["ids"]    
mask = dataset[0]["mask"]
token_type_ids = [0]["token_type_ids"]
```

The problem was that "ids", "mask" and "token_type_ids" are Dictionary Keys. `JigsawDataset` returns a dictionary for each sample. So in order to access a sample we need to specify the index (`[0]`) before specifying the key.